# flutter textfield with tags overflow issue

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a textfield in which on text change I render a list of items if I click on any of the item I am adding it in front of textfield but if I add multiple tags it gives overflow error I want to increase the size of textfiled vertically. Here is the piece of code :

```
///TEXTFIELD
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(
                                    color: AppColor.medGrey, width: 1.5))),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Obx(
                              () => symptomsController.addedSymptoms.isEmpty
                                  ? Container()
                                  : Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                      child: Wrap(
                                        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            WrapCrossAlignment.start,
                                        spacing: 3.0,
                                        children: List.generate(
                                          symptomsController
                                              .addedSymptoms.length,
                                          (index) => Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                color: Colors.brown
                                                    .withOpacity(0.95)),
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 2),
                                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                children: [
                                                  ///SYMPTOM NAME
                                                  Container(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                        "${symptomsController.addedSymptoms[index].commonName}",
                                                        overflow: TextOverflow
                                                            .ellipsis,
                                                        maxLines: 1,
                                                        style: AppTextStyle
                                                            .h6Bright),
                                                  ),

                                                  ///SPACE
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    width: 4,
                                                  ),
                                                  InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      symptomsController
                                                          .searchedList
                                                          .add(symptomsController
                                                                  .addedSymptoms[
                                                              index]);
                                                      symptomsController
                                                          .addedSymptoms
                                                          .removeAt(index);
                                                    },
                                                    child: Icon(
                                                      Icons
                                                          .remove_circle_outline,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      size: 16,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                  controller:
                                      symptomsController.searchQuery.value,
                                  cursorColor: AppColor.highMedGrey,
                                  onChanged: (String query) {
                                    symptomsController.searchString.value =
                                        query;
                                  },
                                  onSubmitted: (String query) {
                                    if (symptomsController
                                            .searchQuery.value.text.length ==
                                        0) {
                                      ///CLEAR LIST OF SYMPTOMS
                                      // symptomsController.searchedList.clear();

                                      return;
                                    } else {
                                      ///CLEAR PREVIOUS LIST OF SYMPTOMS
                                      symptomsController.searchedList.clear();

                                      ///START LOADING
                                      symptomsController.loading.value = true;

                                      ///SEARCH
                                      symptomsController.searchSymptom();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                                  style: AppTextStyle.h4,
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  maxLength: 25,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    counterText: "",
                                    hintText: "Search",
                                    hintStyle: AppTextStyle.h4,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
```

Something like added image.. I want to increase the size vertically...Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the maximum row name for the TextField(). Make sur for it